# in PHP using special characters

Tags: php

In PHP I am trying to write a string in a file.

```
hi hello world<Data="Text">Vtt</Text> How are you
```

but writing this is showing the string with special characters such as `&lt;` and `&gt;`

```
$a = htmlentities($m_str_val);
$str_final = html_entity_decode($a);
```

How can this can be solved?

Comment: Just writing `echo '<';` in PHP does under no circumstances output `&lt;`. It's something you do in your code.

Comment: No.. i am writing the string as it is.. what ouptut i am getting is .. the replacement of '<'  with this &lt;

Answer (score 0):

The [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/function.htmlentities.php) function converts all applicable entities into their HTML equivalent.

`'` will become `&#039;`

`<` will become `&lt;`'

`>` will become `&gt;`

etc.

If you don't want the conversion to happen, don't use htmlentities(). Simply write `$m_str_val` to the file as-is.